# req.body is empty in post api (only in my laptop)

Tags: node.js, express, post

I have created this post API, when I am trying to call it from postman req.body is null always, but the same API is working fine on my friend's laptop.

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true}));

const sayHi = (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hi!");
};

app.get("/", sayHi);

app.post("/add", (req, res) => {
  const { a, b } = req.body;
  console.log(req.body)
  res.send(`The sum is: ${a + b}`);
});

app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port 5000.`);
});
```

this is my postman request: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6QAZ.png

**update:- I tried the same on my other laptop and it is working fine. I don't know why this is not working in my work laptop.**

Comment: Can you please share the postman request here? And also check whether you are passing the a and b as body in your request or as request param

Comment: i have attached screenshot of postman request, and i am passing them as body

Comment: I tried your code and its working on my system as well.

Comment: what you are seeing in the console log for the req.body?

Comment: @mksmanjit i am getting {} in req.body

Answer (score 0):

Hey Once try this middleware and send a proper request from POSTMAN I think this will resolve your all issues..

```
const express = require("express");

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true}));
```

Comment: tried, still not working